# How to retrieve persisted POJOs with Cassandra and Hector Object Mapper

Tags: jpa, orm, cassandra, hector, kundera

I'm trying to play a little bit with the Hector Object Mapper to map pojos to/from Cassandra. Since I'm a newbie in JPA standard, I'm simply trying to persist some basic beans to Cassandra and then get them back. I'm using Hector-object-mapper 3.0-04, Hectore-core 1.0-5, Cassandra server 1.2.2.
So I save my SimpleBean pojo to cassandra with

```
EntityManagerImpl em = new EntityManagerImpl(keyspace, "it.nosql.tests");

SimpleBean simpleBean = new SimpleBean();
simpleBean.setCassandraId(UUID.randomUUID());
simpleBean.setInteger(1000);
simpleBean.setStr("cassandraCrossing");
em.persist(simpleBean);
```

and then i retrieve it specifying the UUID

```
SimpleBean newSB = em.find(SimpleBean.class, simpleBean.getCassandraId());
```

Is there a way to retrieve all the SimpleBean instances persisted to Cassandra without specifying an ID? I expected to have something similar

```
List<SimpleBean> simpleBeanList = em.find(SimpleBean.class).asList();
```

Thanks,
F.

Comment: Did you find your answer elsewhere? I'm Googling this right now myself.

Comment: @Justin I posted the same question on [hector-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hector-users/VieQyiOTyQo), and they suggested to try Firebrand. I eventually ended up with [Kundera](https://code.google.com/p/kundera/), a kind of abstraction layer to interact with Cassandra and other dbs. Kundera was pretty nice and more than enough for my needs.

Comment: thanks for responding. I have gone with Kundera now as well. The original Hector API was great at first but Kundera is more JPA compliant or at least abstracts enough to make it easy; perfect example of the beauty of an API :-D